# Bootstrap 4 TagsInput maxNumTags is not working

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tags-input

I want to set max 5 tags in my input field but `maxNumTags:5` is not working in jquery What should I do to set a maximum value for tagsInput?

HTML

```html
<input
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  id="tags"
  name="tags"
  value="{{ old('tags') }}"
  data-role="tagsinput"
/>
```

And here is the script

```
<script src="dashboard-assets/js/tagsinput.js"></script>
<script>
  $("#tags").tags({
    maxNumTags: 5
  });
</script>
```

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Bootstrap-4-Tag-Input-Plugin-jQuery.html 
from here I used tagsInput js and css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `maxTags` to set the max number of inputs tags. You can also use `allowDuplicates: true` to allow duplicate tags in same input.

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/gh7cy2vf/

Run Snippet below to see it working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tags').tagsinput({
    maxTags: 5,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.js" integrity="sha512-VvWznBcyBJK71YKEKDMpZ0pCVxjNuKwApp4zLF3ul+CiflQi6aIJR+aZCP/qWsoFBA28avL5T5HA+RE+zrGQYg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Type Here: <input type="text"
  class="form-control tags"
  id="tags"
  name="tags" placeholder="Add tags here">
```

Comment: In snippet it also seeing more than 5 tags can entered. can you please check again?

Comment: @tariqulanik Check now - Added a working demo as well.

Comment: see here, I give you screeenshot of your snippet. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GQM0i74uKcbuBQNe8BnIFoX49-CfFbiM/view?usp=sharing 
It keeps more than 5 tags

Comment: @tariqulanik Check my snippet above and JS fiddle as well. Its NOT allowing more then 5 tags.

Comment: @tariqulanik Glad that i could help you.

Comment: you give me bootstrap 3 tagInput, it works in snippet but not in my project. :(

Comment: @tariqulanik Let me update my answer. Please mention this kind of info in the question to make it clear. Thanks

Comment: Please see my title, and my source link.

Comment: @tariqulanik If you want to use maxTags = 5 then do NOT use this your input `data-role="tagsinput"`.

Comment: without mention data-role is it work as tags input?

Comment: @tariqulanik Yes check my JS fiddle and My snippet it works without that Just fine. bootstrap has a native tags input type as well which does not allow limiting but you want limitting you just just normal input. hope this make sense

Comment: @tariqulanik Do not forger to accept the asnwer. Its working as you wanted :) Thanks

Comment: thanks, It's working now. I add the necessary CSS. Thanks for your help @AlwaysHelping :)

Comment: @tariqulanik I am glad its all working. Thanks alot.